# Partition a table and get first and last records in google big query

Tags: google-bigquery, partition

From the below table, I am trying to find the starttime and stoptime for each Id1. 
For example, for Id1 = 103, it started on 2016-11-01 10:50:28 UTC and the stoptime of the vehicle on the same day is on 2016-11-01 11:23:55 UTC.
Similary for id1 = 103, on 2016-12-01, it started on 2016-12-01 10:51:28 UTC and ended on 2016-12-01 11:28:55 UTC.

```
        Id1 Id2 StartTime                 StartDate   StopTime                StopDate    DateTime   
    1   103 314 2016-11-01 10:50:28 UTC 2016-11-01  2016-11-01 11:22:35 UTC 2016-11-01  2016-11-01 10:50:32 UTC  
    2   103 315 2016-11-01 10:50:28 UTC 2016-11-01  2016-11-01 11:22:48 UTC 2016-11-01  2016-11-01 10:50:49 UTC  
    3   103 316 2016-11-01 10:50:28 UTC 2016-11-01  2016-11-01 11:22:55 UTC 2016-11-01  2016-11-01 10:50:54 UTC  
    4   103 317 2016-11-01 10:50:28 UTC 2016-11-01  2016-11-01 11:23:55 UTC 2016-11-01  2016-11-01 10:51:03 UTC  
    5   103 318 2016-12-01 10:51:28 UTC 2016-12-01  2016-12-01 11:24:15 UTC 2016-12-01  2016-12-01 10:51:19 UTC  
    6   103 319 2016-12-01 10:52:28 UTC 2016-12-01  2016-12-01 11:25:55 UTC 2016-12-01  2016-12-01 10:51:24 UTC  
    7   103 320 2016-12-01 10:53:28 UTC 2016-12-01  2016-12-01 11:26:55 UTC 2016-12-01  2016-12-01 10:51:31 UTC  
    8   103 321 2016-12-01 10:54:28 UTC 2016-12-01  2016-12-01 11:27:55 UTC 2016-12-01  2016-12-01 10:51:40 UTC  
    9   103 322 2016-12-01 10:55:28 UTC 2016-12-01  2016-12-01 11:28:55 UTC 2016-12-01  2016-12-01 10:51:43 UTC  

    Output:
        Id1 StartTime                 StartDate   StopTime                StopDate    
    1   103 2016-11-01 10:50:28 UTC 2016-11-01  2016-11-01 11:23:55 UTC 2016-11-01  
    5   103 2016-12-01 10:51:28 UTC 2016-12-01  2016-12-01 11:28:55 UTC 2016-12-01
```

I tried with the below query, but not sure why it does not work:

```
          SELECT Id1, Date, StartTime, StopTime 
          FROM(
          SELECT
            Id1,
            DATE(DateTime) AS Date,
            FIRST_VALUE(StartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Id1, DATE(DateTime)  ORDER BY DateTime) AS StartTime,
            LAST_VALUE(StopTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Id1, DATE(DateTime) ORDER BY DateTime ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS StopTime,
          FROM
            TestSridevi.ET_Time_Leaving)
          GROUP BY Id1, Date, StartTime, StopTime
          ORDER BY Id1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving first and last records of each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765036/retrieving-first-and-last-records-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 103 AS Id1, 314 AS Id2, '2016-11-01 10:50:28 UTC' AS StartTime, '2016-11-01' AS StartDate, '2016-11-01 11:22:35 UTC' AS StopTime, '2016-11-01' AS StopDate, '2016-11-01 10:50:32 UTC' AS DateTime UNION ALL  
  SELECT 103, 315, '2016-11-01 10:50:28 UTC', '2016-11-01', '2016-11-01 11:22:48 UTC', '2016-11-01', '2016-11-01 10:50:49 UTC' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 103, 316, '2016-11-01 10:50:28 UTC', '2016-11-01', '2016-11-01 11:22:55 UTC', '2016-11-01', '2016-11-01 10:50:54 UTC' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 103, 317, '2016-11-01 10:50:28 UTC', '2016-11-01', '2016-11-01 11:23:55 UTC', '2016-11-01', '2016-11-01 10:51:03 UTC' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 103, 318, '2016-12-01 10:51:28 UTC', '2016-12-01', '2016-12-01 11:24:15 UTC', '2016-12-01', '2016-12-01 10:51:19 UTC' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 103, 319, '2016-12-01 10:52:28 UTC', '2016-12-01', '2016-12-01 11:25:55 UTC', '2016-12-01', '2016-12-01 10:51:24 UTC' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 103, 320, '2016-12-01 10:53:28 UTC', '2016-12-01', '2016-12-01 11:26:55 UTC', '2016-12-01', '2016-12-01 10:51:31 UTC' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 103, 321, '2016-12-01 10:54:28 UTC', '2016-12-01', '2016-12-01 11:27:55 UTC', '2016-12-01', '2016-12-01 10:51:40 UTC' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 103, 322, '2016-12-01 10:55:28 UTC', '2016-12-01', '2016-12-01 11:28:55 UTC', '2016-12-01', '2016-12-01 10:51:43 UTC'   
)
SELECT
  Id1,
  MIN(StartTime) AS StartTime,
  StartDate,
  MAX(StopTime) AS StopTime,
  StopDate
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Id1, StartDate, StopDate
ORDER BY Id1, StartDate, StopDate
```

result is

```sql
Id1               StartTime  StartDate                 StopTime   stopDate   
103 2016-11-01 10:50:28 UTC 2016-11-01  2016-11-01 11:23:55 UTC 2016-11-01   
103 2016-12-01 10:51:28 UTC 2016-12-01  2016-12-01 11:28:55 UTC 2016-12-01
```